# Find: Children's book illustrator

Tags: self-publishing, book, children, artwork

I need an illustrator for my first self-published children's book.

1. Where do I find artists that will work on a small budget?
2. What are the compensation options?
3. How do I find an artist that specializes in multi-racial characters?
4. If an illustrator is not in the budget, is there a software program that can turn photos into illustrations?
5. What should I expect for a 20-page book that has 15 illustrations?

Comment: This seems broad for Writers.SE. In particular, we try to answer focused questions; having five different questions in a single post doesn't work very well within the Q&A format, and it's usually an indication that the question should be split up - or that it's broader than we can manage. In this case, it sounds like you need a full introduction to searching for illustrators, with a few particular details besides. Which seems to me beyond the scope of what we can meaningfully answer here. Folks, what do you think?

Comment: Thank you @Standback for your valuable advise.  To me, my inquiry was a direct question about finding an illustrator.  After reading your post, I can see how certain individuals might read it differently.  In the future, I'll do my best to limit my inquiries to exclude particular details .  Again, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Thank you @KaiMaxfield for the advise about kickstarter.com.  I will look into it.  Thanks!

Comment: David, you might want to focus your query on your largest remaining question if you would like to generate further interest and/or answers. E.g. Where can I find reasonably priced illustrators and/or a software counterpart. You also might hit the [Software Recommendations SE site.](http://goo.gl/Ib3T58) Depending on the Stack Exchange site, once comments like Standback's comment start appearing on a question or answer, the chances are pretty good that [closure](http://goo.gl/iwbnho) will follow unless revisions are made. Also, see [this question](http://goo.gl/3D9OlZ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for artists on their webcomic sites, like Cucumber Quest, Hark! a Vagrant or Helvetica, you may have some luck.

Also, check out Deviant Art for users with worldwide artistic talents

Answer (score 0):

> If an illustrator is not in the budget, is there a software program that can turn photos into illustrations?

Many image editing programs have a feature called Effects or Filters that can transform a photo in many ways. [Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) probably has the widest range of choices, though there are also free alternatives. The image below was created using [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) (Effects menu / Artistic / Ink Sketch...). There are quite a few [plugins for Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/InstallPlugins.html) that offer a variety of effects (pay attention to the big red warning on the plugins page). [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is another popular, free choice.

Effects for all image editing programs have a variety of parameters you can tweak to adjust the look.

You will probably get much better results if a quality illustrator is in your budget.

[image]